# Turtlebot3 description not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had issues with my ROS since some packages were deleted (https://answers.ros.org/question/390335/python3-rosdep2-install-broke-ros/), so tried re-installing. Now I'm getting this error:

```
Resource not found: turtlebot3_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/roshan/Documents/ROS/turtlebot_test/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/noetic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

And looking through the files in the /opt/ros/noetic/share, there is no turtlebot3_description. Have done

> source devel/setup.bash

, still getting the error. Have also tried reinstalling the turtlebot3_simulations package in my workspace and catkin_make, still getting the issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390340/turtlebot3-description-not-found./) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had to manually install this package, which is weird since it used to come automatically when installing ROS Noetic or turtlebot3 sim

---

Originally posted by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) with karma: 51 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

How were you able to solve it? I am having the same problems right now .
Already done  export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger  but still same problem

[image]